# What is the best route to see the most typically English landscapes/towns in the Centre of England in three days?

Tags: uk

We have only, say, 3 days to explore what I call the centre of England - i.e. in a square from Leeds to Bury-St-Edmunds to Oxford to Newtown (near the A489 motorway). This will be from 17 October.

We are doing York after this, and also going further north.

I realise that there are countless picturesque towns and villages throughout the UK.

Could you suggest a road trip where we might see/find a lot of the beautiful stone fences, country lanes, picturesque towns and villages, green farming landscapes, quaint/rustic but popular pubs? We want to see that which is VERY English!

Also, are there any country fairs/markets/festivals still happening, though I realise that a lot of them happen in the warmer months?

Comment: This is a great question but off-topic on this site. I'd go to a tourist information office in Oxford and ask them for ideas and information. P.S. The A489 is an "A-road" not a "motorway" - Motorways have names starting with an M) There are also B-roads and unclassified roads.

Comment: RedGrittyBricks last point is a good one, in particular because there are different road regulations that apply to Motorways and "A-Roads". Although some stretch of "A-Road" are classed as motorways and they will have names such as the A1-M.

Comment: "Could you suggest a road trip where we might see/find a lot of the beautiful stone fences, country lanes, picturesque towns and villages, green farming landscapes, quaint/rustic but popular pubs? " For me, that's Cornwall, in the opposite direction.  So yes, this question, however wonderful in spirit, is an opinion survey, hence off-topic, sorry.

Comment: "We want to see that which is VERY English!" - Don't go to country towns then, go to London suburbs. 1 in 6 people in England live in London. Unless rather than "VERY English" you mean "our romanticised view of English based on watching TV shows set 100 years ago"! In which case you may want to consider driving around the Peak District National Park.

Answer (score 4):

England is not a very big country but, nonetheless, that's a large area to explore in 3 days.

Oxford is certainly worth a day (bias warning, I studied there long ago).

Stratford-upon-Avon which is the birthplace of Shakespeare.

Warwick Castle, it's quite expensive to visit but it is the best preserved castle in the country.

All of those are within a reasonable distance of each other.  Also, all will be full of tourists.

I need to speak to my wife to get some market advice though her favourites are mostly in cities and you seem to want smaller towns.  Markets in smaller towns are often only on specific days.

Further ideas.

Bletchley Park which is where Alan Turing and others cracked the German Enigma code.

I have not got there myself yet but look up the Black Country Living Museum.

Tell us some more about your interests and I may be able to make some more suggestions.

Look at these:

[National Trust](https://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/home)

[English Heritage](http://www.english-heritage.org.uk)